# comparing object identifier with string

Tags: c++

is there any possibilities to compare object identifier with string idiom without adding any member e.g. string variable variable to the class?

```
struct ObjectExample {}ObEX;


string St;
cin >> St >> endl; // you enter ObEX

// What I need to reach is this comparing 
if(obEX == St)
{......}
```

As you see both object have different data type..

## Edit

If the comparison not possible. I would re-formalize  my question:

is there any technique to copy the object identifier to  a string object.

The whole issue is if you can NOt modify or adding the class definition but you can only create instances of it and you want to compare  a string name with the object identifier!!!

Comment: You can, but in general you really shouldn’t. This looks confusing and potentially subverts the type system. Equality testing should follow certain rules which are potentially violated here.

Comment: Why would you want this? Perhaps something like `map<string, ObjectExample>` mapping a runtime identifier to an ObjectExample instance would help?

Answer (score 3):

You overload the operator `==` for your struct `ObjectExample`.

```
struct ObjectExample
{
    bool operator ==(const std::string &str)
    {
         //do the necessary comparison and return a bool
    }

};
```

Ofcourse, You can only compare two things if they have some comparable trait. If your `ObjectExample` does not have any `string` type member then, You are essentially trying to compare Apples with Oranges, which doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you propose to implement the necessary comparison.

Comment: @visitor: Did you read the later part of the answer or just ignore it?

Comment: I don't see why having a string member is essential to make something comparable to a string. I may well be able to create a string representation of the object etc. The question seems to be: how to get the identifier of a variable at runtime, not what's the syntax for overloading `operator==`. - As far as I can see the correct answer is the downvoted answer of Gorpik (or any answer suggesting a work-around).

Comment: @visitor:Well, `question seems to be` It didn't seem anything that would provide any different answer from above,since the first time it was posted.You are free to add your own answer or upvote an answer you think is correct.You don't need to ask me for that.

Comment: In the interest of clear code, I personally use a `ToString()` method in the object instead of `operator ==`. It makes sure you know the object is being converted to a string identifier and it's not an actual comparison going on.